# What is the difference between stoichiometric coefficients and number of moles?

Tags: thermodynamics, stoichiometry, mole

Please clear my doubt,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stoichiometric coefficients are defined once and for all for a given reaction. They are integers. It is 2 for H2 and 1 for O2 in the reaction 2H2+O2->2H2O

The number of moles depends only on the particular experiment. It may be any number, integer or not.